# java system.out.printf format numerics rounding off and spacing issue together

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Solution {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] languages = { "java", "cpp", "python" };
        int[] values = { 100, 65, 60 };

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%-5s %03d %n", languages[i], values[i]);
            //Complete this line
        }
    }
}
```

Output I'm getting

```
java 100
cpp 65
python 50
```

Desired output

```
java           100 
cpp            065 
python         050
```

Comment: It would be easier to reproduce this if you just hard-coded the data into your program... mind if I do that?

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of changing `%-5s` to `%-15s`?

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry i couldnt get you . please make me clear . i am new user .

Comment: Also, the output you show here must be from a previous version of the program. It is not from the exact code posted in the question at least.

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("================================");
            
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                String s1=sc.next();
                int x=sc.nextInt();
                System.out.printf("%-5s %03d %n",s1,x);
                //Complete this line
            }
            System.out.println("================================");

    }
}code  is working but i can not able to meet the desired output

Comment: @Keppil  thk . can you please tell m the "-" sign meaning before % s

Comment: I mean that in order to reproduce the problem, we have to type stuff into the console. There's no need for that. Will edit so you can see what I mean.

Comment: The ´-´ makes the text left-aligned instead of right-aligned.

Comment: Btw, when I run this code I get 065 and 050 displayed, not 65 and 50... are you sure you're seeing the output you put into the question?

Answer (score 2):

The code you've got doesn't match the output you've shown - it's *nearly* right already. It comes up with:

```
java  100 
cpp   065 
python 060
```

The only problem here is that you're right-padding the names to a minimum of 5 characters... but python has 6 characters. So you just need to increase the `5` in your format string. For example:

```
System.out.printf("%-10s %03d %n", languages[i], values[i]);
```

Separately, your comments have suggested that you don't know what each of the bits of your format string does. You should read the [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) documentation carefully. For example, the `-` in `%-10s` is a flag, with a meaning of "The result will be left-justified."

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.out.printf("%-15s %03d %n", s1, x);
```

where s1 is a string and x is a number.

Explanation:

```
 in the above code -15s is defined as follows : - is for left justified, and width is specified as 15. s is to print the string
 in the above code  %03d is defined as follows.

    0 - to pad with zeros
    3 - width of the field was set as 3.

Running the program:
        ================================
        java 100(input)
        java           100
        cpp 65(input)
        cpp            065
        ================================

Now the second line output "100", starts at the 16th character/position.Also it is padding 0 in the 4th line output.
```

Comment: but this is not meeting the exact output . @keppil i am running this code   but its editor is displaying the wrong answer

Comment: actually this is ques from challenge and its editor is supporting the "NO SPACE" between the "%-15s%03d%n" . however you idea help me to correct the code .. thks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("================================");
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                String s1=sc.next();
                int x=sc.nextInt();
                //Complete this line
                System.out.print(s1 );
                System.out.print("\t\t");

                System.out.println(x);


            }
            System.out.println("================================");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("%-15s%03d%n", s1, x);
```

I don't know why but removing white-spaces inside "" works.

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("================================");
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                String s1=sc.next();
                int x=sc.nextInt();
                System.out.printf("%-15s",s1);
                System.out.printf("%03d",x);
                System.out.println("");
            }
            System.out.println("================================");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("================================");
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                String s1=sc.next();
                int x=sc.nextInt();
                //Complete this line
                System.out.printf("%-14s %03d %n",s1,x);
            }
            System.out.println("================================");
    }
}
```